# use JQuery to get siblings

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the a tag below to grab the value from the select and paste it into the input.

```
<td class="ms-formbody" style="width:385px">
    <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$dlFields$ctl00$txtSource" type="text" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dlFields_ctl00_txtSource" class="ms-input" />
    <select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$dlFields$ctl00$ddlSourceFields" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dlFields_ctl00_ddlSourceFields" class="ms-input">
        <option value="Some Field Name 1">Some Field Name 1</option>
        <option value="Some Field Name 2">Some Field Name 2</option>
        <option value="Some Field Name 3">Some Field Name 3</option>
        <option value="Some Field Name 4">Some Field Name 4</option>
    </select>
    <a href="javascript: appendField();">append</a>
</td>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to grab siblings. I tried `$(this).siblings("input").val()` but that errored Webpage error `'parentNode.firstChild' is null or not an object`.

Tried `$(this).prev().prev().val()` and that comes back undefined. What's the best way to grab these things?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your issue stems from your approach. Calling a function directly won't do what you're expecting, which is to have a jquery object representing the <a> tag. Rather than call a function directly you can register a function to respond to a `click` event on the <a>.

First, give your link an id:

```
<a href="#" id="appendSelect">append</a>
```

Then use replace your `appendField()` function with a jQuery select that responds to `click`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#appendSelect").click(function() {
    var $thatInput = $(this).siblings("input");
    var $selectValue = $(this).siblings("select").val();
    $thatInput.val($selectValue);
  })
});
```

With this approach `$(this)` will represent your <a>.

You can see what I'm talking about to a greater depth by using a javascript debugging console (chrome has one by default, and you can use Firebug on Firefox). Try your original function based approach again and add a `console.log($(this));` statement. You should see it printing out a DOMWindow object. Now put the same log statement in the `click` function and you'll see that jQuery has given you a $(this) representing what you expected it to be.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was really helpful. Following your lead, I wrapped my tabe with a div and then grabbed that and that worked wonderfully

$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myList a").click(function () {                
                var $selectValue = $(this).siblings("select").val();
                var $thatInput = $(this).siblings("input");
                                $thatInput.val($selectValue);
            })
        });

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
$(this).parent().children("input:first").val();
```

Comment: didn't work, see previous posts above, I think it's an issue with my approach

Answer (score 1):

The appendfield method does not access to $(this).

Here is the working code:
http://jsfiddle.net/NBf4d/2/

Comment: JSFiddle is AMAZING! I modified the code a bit to more of my environment. I forgot to mention it's a repeating row, and I updated using anothers JQUery samples. Still tweaking it.

Answer (score 0):

use .children() or .find()

.children only looks for direct children of the parent, find looks at all levels below the parent.

`$('.ms-formbody').find('select').val();`

Answer (score 0):

This will only work for these IDs, but you can easily change them:

```
$('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dlFields_ctl00_txtSource').val($('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dlFields_ctl00_ddlSourceFields').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(this).parent().find('input:first').val(selectedOptionValue);
```

Comment: didn't work, see previous posts above, I think it's an issue with my approach